# possible bug with code highlight

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I just finished an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32405036, and found the highlighting is broken.

This works ok:

```sql
replace(src_path,'/','') src_path,
```

But this causes weird things, where code is highlighted as string:

```sql
replace(src_path,'\','/') src_path,
```

[image]
Looks like [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b98ea/16) has same error.

Comment: The syntax highlighting is indeed correct. By saying \' you are escaping an apostrophe to appear in cleartext. This doesn't close the string, and so the string continues on until a non-escaped ' is being found. 
Test e.g. in your webbrowser's javascript console: 
alert('\') 
and 
alert('\'')

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt yes but sql doesnt have that sintaxis. How I fix the color highlight without changing the code i want to show. I mean I can change '\' for '\'' and color is good again.  But that isn't the code I want to display.

Comment: I can't see the code no matter how hard I try.  My eye inevitably glances at the drastically screwed up blue border.  Eek.  Was there any point in adding those distractions?

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, when I add the first picture looks like code instead a picture. I Will change to a less bright border

Comment: @HansPassant Done, send me any medical bill if you need buy new glassess.

Comment: Between apostrophes the `\ ` character does not produce escapes in at least some languages. [space inserted as I would actually get weird things: `\`